# Woocommerce do action does not work in Ajax functions, but works when hardcoded to php file

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I have created a simple popup on a test page where I load the product summary of a variable product. When I paste the following code in the php file directly, it works perfectly.

```html
global $product;
$product = wc_get_product(14);

do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

But if I insert it via ajax through functions.php, the variable prices are missing and when the product is added to cart, I get an error message saying that "Please choose product options by visiting BBQ Chicken Pizza".

Here's the jquery function.

```js
$('.product_parent_tabs .variable_a2c_btn').click(function(){

    var prod_id = $(this).attr("data-prod") ; 

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'cus_product_popup_ajax', // This is our PHP function below
            'prod_id' : prod_id // This is the variable we are sending via AJAX
        },
        success:function(data) {
    // This outputs the result of the ajax request (The Callback)
            $('#cus_popup .cus_popup_details').html(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            window.alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

functions.php code below

```html
function cus_product_popup_ajax() {

    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        $prod_id = $_REQUEST['prod_id'];

        global $product;
        $product = wc_get_product(14);

        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );

    }

    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_cus_product_popup_ajax', 'cus_product_popup_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cus_product_popup_ajax', 'cus_product_popup_ajax' );
```

Any insights on this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When doing AJAX there is no **global $product** as the AJAX requests are independent.

More or less here's the solution to your problem which should work:

```
$prod_id = $_REQUEST['prod_id'];

$product = wc_get_product($prod_id);

do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', $product );
```

This should force the action to take $product into consideration and print all stuff for that product.

Let me know if this worked for you.